# Ionic 3 sidemenu from list page to home page not going

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, side-menu

I have created an app with ionic 3 sidemenu.

When I go to the list page I can't go back to the home page with the back button.

Instead, then the app got closed.

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code sample is needed. How do you navigate between pages ?

Comment: Nothing did special. Fully fresh template.

Comment: check your code. if you see something like `this.nav.setRoot` that means the page you selected will be the root page and the navigation stack is cleared. change it to `this.nav.push(yourpage)`

Comment: Thanks  for your help, It works but the in list page now bread crumb menu disappeared

Answer (score 0):

According to ionic V3 sidemenu starter, pages are set as root, you can check openPage(page) function on this [github](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/blob/master/ionic-angular/official/sidemenu/src/app/app.component.ts) link of sidemenu starter of ionic team.

*When a page is set to root all the previous navigation stack is cleared.*

If you want to change this behavior you have to use this.nav.push(page).